# Name conflict in DLL exports leads to wrong function exported

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, dll

I exported a function from a DLL, using a .def file, similar to this:

```
void __stdcall remove(FlagFile* flagP)
{
    if (flagP == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    delete flagP;
}
```

Trying to call the function, I received crashes I couldn't place, until I saw in the disassembler that instead of calling the code above, the linker had exported a different function from the CRT instead, and then that function was called in place of the function I expected to be called. This resulted in a stack corruption, likely because the function above has void result, as opposed to CRT's remove(), which returns int. The solution was to simply rename the exported function to resolve the name conflict. Unfortunately, MSVC does not give a warning about the name conflict.

(Just putting this here so people can object if my analysis is wrong. This post hopefully gives others a clue who run into a similar problem.)

This was observed with MSVC 2019 under Windows 11. Not sure if it applies to other compilers/operating systems (shared libraries in that case).

So the question would be: aside from giving all functions a prefix (like OpenGL's gl), what are your strategies for dealing with this problem, if it ever was a problem?

Comment: Is the caller using the same convention (`__stdcall`)? Can you please provide an example of the calling code?

Comment: There is no question in your post. If the comment about soliciting people to object is intended to be the reason for the post, rephrase it into a question. In any case, this is fully documented. `remove` is specified in C 2018 7.21.4.1, and 7.1.3 says that these identifiers declared in the library headers are reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope, and that “If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: My guess is that your `remove` function was packaged into a `.lib` and the `.dll` was generated from that `.lib` plus the C runtime `.lib`. The linker then looks in the `.lib` files in the order passed to the linker, and if you put the C runtime one first, then that's the one it gets. It's a feature that the linker stops searching once it finds a match: This lets you override a function from one library with a function in another library. And that's what you accidentally did here. You told it to override your library with the C runtime. (Moral of the story: Don't create name conflicts.)

Comment: I agree with Eric.  This is a Q&A site.  While knowledge sharing is encouraged, it still needs to be in a Q&A format. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)